# How to correctly get data from fragment to parent activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have activity that contains A and B fragment. I used FrameLayout and BottomNavigation. I use following method to change fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame, selectedFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

And i have one menu in activity which contains printer and mail. When i click printer or mail button from Activity. Activity have to get data from Fragment A or Fragment B. It's kind of sale process.

If Sale process is success i clear data of Fragment A and B. B contains lot of items. A contains one item.

My problem is I use Global variables to pass data.

Fragment B:

```
public static List<Product> ProductList = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Product> itemSaleProductList = new ArrayList<>();
public static double itemSaleTotalPrice = 0;
```

Fragment A:

```
public static Product quickSale = null;
```

After user click item i save data. And when user click printer button it gets data from Global variables. Also If global variables have a value, Fragment B and A have to get that values.

It works. But Sometimes it can't get values. So How to get data correctly from activity?

Comment: Communicate using interfaces - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html and never, ever, ever use global mutable variables.

Comment: When activity begins I have to download productList and divide data. Data goes to Fragment A or Fragment B.

Comment: Sometimes FragmentB have to download productList and divide data. Some data have to go FragmentA. Some data have to remain Fragment B

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make a setter from your activity then do this from your fragment

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setProductList(itemSaleProductList);
```

hope this helps

Comment: and when i choose items from fragments how to get data from activity?

Comment: Or I have to write same code in fragment A and B. Also my printer code is fairly huge.

Comment: Let me clear it out.. You have 1 activity that calls fragmentA, then when user click item from fragmentA, it open fragmentB and display the chosen item? Is my logic correct?

Comment: no, Fragment A collects FragmentA data and Fragment B collects FragmentB data.